# URL mapping not works as I want

Tags: django

[Header section main-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baGnS.png)
By selecting 'About' from the main-page-options, /app1/about template is called, which is fine. However by selecting the Portfolio-drop-down items, I get an error. That is because the item is saved in mysite/app1/template folder and django is looking in the root of mysite. How can I map it?

```
# Here is my mysite/app1/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from app1 import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('services/', views.services, name='services'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('portfolio1/', views.portfolio1, name='portfolio1'),    
]

# part of my views.py
def portfolio1 (request):
    return render (request, 'portfolio1.html')

404 Error:
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL 
patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
app1/
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, portfolio1.html, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Your path is `/portfolio1`, *not* `/portfolio1.html`

Comment: Thank you Willem,

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Willem, I get the point:

I made a correction in my base.html and issue solved:
before correction:
    Portfolio 1
after correction:
    Portfolio 1